# How to simplify a nested if statement tree

Tags: javascript, loops, if-statement

I have a nested if statement tree that runs a function 16 times (I know), each time sending in a different set of elements to the function.

The function simply returns true or false.

```
if(!checkSpecial(1,1,1,1)) {
    if(!checkSpecial(1,1,1,0)) {
        if(!checkSpecial(1,1,0,1)) {
            if(!checkSpecial(1,0,1,1)) {
                if(!checkSpecial(0,1,1,1)) {                                
                    if(!checkSpecial(1,1,0,0)) {                            
                        if(!checkSpecial(1,0,0,1)) {                            
                            if(!checkSpecial(0,0,1,1)) {                            
                                if(!checkSpecial(1,0,1,0)) {                            
                                    if(!checkSpecial(0,1,0,1)) {                            
                                        if(!checkSpecial(0,1,1,0)) {                    
                                            if(!checkSpecial(1,0,0,0)) {                    
                                                if(!checkSpecial(0,1,0,0)) {                    
                                                    if(!checkSpecial(0,0,1,0)) {                    
                                                        if(!checkSpecial(0,0,0,1)) {                    
                                                            if(!checkSpecial(0,0,0,0)) {
                                                            }
                                                        }
                                                    }
                                                }
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }   
} else {
    // do other stuff
}
```

as you can see, if the function returns false in every single one of those instances, I want to do other things.

I don't want to do anything if the function returns true.

My question is, I know there has to be a better way of doing this, I'm assuming through some sort of loop, but I'm not aware of what this type of loop would be called or how it would work.

My fix so far:

```
for (var i = 0; i < 16; i++) { 
   // HELP!
}
```

Any pointers would be appreciated. thank you.

Comment: 1. Convert `i` to an 4 bits, stored in an array as 1 and 0. 2. use `Function.prototype.apply`

Comment: Without seeing what the function does it's pretty hard to offer advice.

Comment: I don't see how knowing what the function does matters. It requests 4 inputs of either 1 or zero and then gives a true or false answer. For all it matters, the function can do nothing at all except always return false... the point is how can I simplify the if statements.

Comment: As @Pointy has said, without knowing what the function achieves it's hard to offer anything solid. The only advice I can offer is to store each permutation in an array and iterate over that instead of writing every if statement.

Comment: Can you abort once one call returns true?

Comment: absolutely, yes you can

Answer (score 1):

You can create an array of the binary representation of numbers 0-15, and then check if `every` one of them returns false when calling the function with the array items as arguments:

```js
const combinations = Array.from(
  { length: 16 },
  (_, i) => (i >>> 0).toString(2).padStart(4, '0').split('').map(Number)
);

console.log(combinations)
/*
if (combinations.every(combination => checkSpecial(...combination) === false)) {
  // every result was false
} else {
  // at least one result wasn't false
}
*/
```

Comment: This duplicates some values (eg, `[1,0,0,0]`)

Answer (score 0):

My only suggestion is as follows:

1. Initialize an array with every permutation

```js
var permutations = [
 [0, 1, 1, 0],
  [1, 1, 1, 0]
];
```

2. Iterate over those permutations and do what you need

```js
permutations.forEach(function(permutation) {
    if (checkSpecial(permutation[0], permutation[1], permutation[2], permutation[3])) {

    } else {

    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an idea with the for loop. Plug this into your VS

```
     int a = 0;
     int b = 0;
     int c = 0;
     int d = 0;


     for (a = 0; a <= 1; a++)
     {
        for (b = 0; b <= 1; b++)
        {
           for (c = 0; c <= 1; c++)
           {
              for (d = 0; d <= 1; d++)
              {
                 Console.WriteLine($"function({a}, {b}, {c}, {d})");
              }
           }
        }
     }
     Console.ReadKey();
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
function* bin(){
  yield 0;
  yield 1;
}
function* word(size,prefix){
  if(!prefix){
    prefix=[];
  }
  if(size){
    var b=bin(),
        n;
    while((n=b.next()) && !n.done){
      prefix[size-1]=n.value;
      yield* word(size-1,prefix);
    }
  } else {
    yield prefix;
  }
}

var w=word(4),
    cond=true,
    n;
while((n=w.next())&&!n.done){
  if(checkSpecial.apply(n.value)){
    cond=false;
    break;
  }
}

if(cond){

} else {

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make a for loop something like this..

```
boolean checkConditions() {
        int[][] cond = {
                {1, 1, 1, 1},
                {1, 1, 1, 0},
                {1, 1, 0, 1},
                {1, 0, 1, 1},
                {0, 1, 1, 1},
                {1, 1, 0, 0},
                {1, 0, 0, 1},
                {0, 0, 1, 1},
                {1, 0, 1, 0},
                {0, 1, 1, 0},
                {0, 1, 0, 1},
                {1, 0, 0, 0},
                {0, 1, 0, 0},
                {0, 0, 1, 0},
                {0, 0, 0, 1},
                {0, 0, 0, 0}};

        for (int i = 0; i < cond.length; i++) {
            if(checkSpecial(cond[i][0], cond[i][1], cond[i][2], cond[i][3])) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        // do other stuff
    }
```